# how to show all commited sql files in git from a specific commit on

Tags: git

I would like to find out if it is possible to get an ordered list of sql files that were commited to git from a specific commit on til the last commit?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
git diff --name-only commit_hash -- '*.sql' | sort
```

Comment: great ... actualy I had to put -- between the hash and the file name like this git diff --name-only 385c419 -- '*.sql' | sort, please repair the answer an i will mark it as correct

Comment: what about if I want to sort by cronologic order an not by name?